# Is there an advanced search for SoundCloud?

Tags: search, music, soundcloud

I know I can filter results by license and some preselected ranges:

[image]

But is there any way to do more than this? For example:

- Search for tracks between 2:30 and 2:45 in length
- Remove particular terms from the results - e.g. `-"artist influence"` to remove artist influence interviews?

Comment: It seems the only way is to use a third party front-end, like http://mycloudplayers.com/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry mikemaccana, but their isn't a way to do that unless you get a third-party app with those kind of advanced search capabilities.